# Не копируются зависимости в maven

Tags: java, maven, зависимости

При сборке проекта в maven в jar не копируются зависимости, поэтому при запуске `NoClassDefFoundError`. 
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

так же думаю, что maven-dependency-plugin просто не выполняется, потому что в выводе при сборке из консоли просто нет такого плагина. С Shade ситуация аналогична.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать плагин версии 3+ (2-й откровенно староват).
2. goal - в зависимости от того, в каком виде хранится copy/unpack
3. В конфигурации artifactItems - не указаны явно.

Пример боевого конфига с распаковкой зависимостей protobuf:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-protoc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                                <artifactId>protoc</artifactId>
                                <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
                                <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
                                <type>exe</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-google-libraries-protobuf</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                                <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${google.external.proto.libs}</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>google/protobuf/*.proto</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Если нужно собирать jar-ник с зависимостями, то советую использовать maven-shade-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>executable</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: А что нужно менять в вашем конфиге с shade плагином?

Comment: По идее указать свой запускаемый mainClass 
 <mainClass>Main</mainClass>, а если его нет, то удалить эту строку.

${project.artifactId} - у вас заполнен.
outputDirectory - ${project.basedir}/target например.

Этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Нужно ли использовать maven jar plugin вместе с maven shade plugin? если без него, то при запуске `no main manifest attribute, in Example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
`

Comment: Достаточно `maven-compiler-plugin` в связке с `maven-shade-plugin`. Главное указать путь к вашему main классу. Еще не стоит допускать пересечения имён выходных jar-ников. Для этого указывается finalName например без version. В результате `maven-compiler-plugin` соберет SNAPSHOT (jar без зависимостей и не запускаемый), а `maven-shade-plugin` соберет jar-ник в котором будут все зависимости необходимые для работы программы. Название будет без SNAPSHOT, если указать `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`

Comment: сделал так, как вы сказали, но в jar-нике все равно нет библиотек.

Comment: Уберите из pom.xml тэг `pluginManagement`. Из-за него не запускается maven-shade-plugin.
[Чтиво-Executable JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html). pom.xml нужно настраивать очень внимательно.

Comment: А как установить в Maven shade plugin версию jdk?

Comment: Все, разобрался. надо было еще добавить compile-plugin

Comment: при работе maven-shade -plugin создает два jar файла. Каким образом можно было бы убрать original-jar?

Comment: Compiler плагин создаёт jar без зависимостей, shade с зависимостями. Это нормальное поведение, так и должно быть.